# Javascript: Create object array with functions directly inline

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, javascript-objects

I'm looking for a solution to create an angular directive to create a view dynamically. To use it I would like to pass an array of objects defined "inline". This objects contain a couple label/function.

When I define an array into a scope and pass his content to element attribute it works, however when I define the same into "inline" attribute it throws me "Syntax error".

Whats is worgn? Is there possible to do this?

HTML/JS:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('MainApp', []);

  app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myButtons = [{
        label: "Hellow!",
        onclick: function() {
          alert("Hellow!")
        }
      }, {
        label: "Bye!",
        onclick: function() {
          alert("Bye!")
        }
      }];
    }
  ]);

  app.directive('vgButtons', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        buttons: '=buttons'
      },
      template: '<div>' +
        'Buttons:<br>' +
        '<button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click="button.onclick()">' +
        '{{button.label}}' +
        '</button>' +
        '</div>'
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  {{myButtons}}
  <!-- Works perfect with scope object -->
  <vg-buttons buttons='myButtons'>
  </vg-buttons>
  <!-- Works with "inline" defined array, but without define functions -->
  <vg-buttons buttons='[{label:"Hellow!", onclick: null}, {label:"Bye!", onclick: null}]'>
  </vg-buttons>
  <!-- Works with "inline" defined array, but functions doesn't work -->
  <vg-buttons buttons='[{label:"Hellow!", onclick: alert("Hellow!")}, {label:"Bye!", onclick: alert("Bye!")}]'>
  </vg-buttons>
  <!-- Doesn't work with "inline" functions (I WANTED THIS SOLUTION) -->
  <vg-buttons buttons='[{label:"Hellow!", onclick: function(){alert("Hellow!")}}, {label:"Bye!", onclick: function{alert("Bye!")}}]'>
  </vg-buttons>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ### No function declarations or RegExp creation with literal notation
>
> You can't declare functions or create regular expressions from within AngularJS expressions. This is to avoid complex model transformation logic inside templates. Such logic is better placed in a controller or in a dedicated filter where it can be tested properly.

-- [AngularJS Guide Expressions -- no function declarations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#no-function-declarations-or-regexp-creation-with-literal-notation)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will use it as scope object then.